# Gatling 2.0.3 - Mapping values to template

Tags: gatling

I am trying to Map values to the templete. I am testing web services. I need to populate response from the first rest call to another rest call as a request. I am doing in the below.

The first POST call [BOLDED] and I am saving the response into two values. Now I am passing the values to another POST call[BOLDED ITALIC].

I am getting the below error. Please help to solve this issue
too many arguments for method body:

> (bd:io.gatling.http.request.Body)io.gatling.http.request.builder.HttpRequestWithParamsBuilder

val authorization = scenario("Authorization")
  .feed(correlationIdFeeder) 
  .feed(dataFeeder) 
  .feed(csvFeeder)
  .exec(
    http("Creating tm token given an external token")
      .post(tokenization_endpoint)
      **.body(ELFileBody("tokenization.json")).asJSON

      .check(status.is(200))

      .check(jsonPath("$.payment_token").saveAs("payment_token"))**
      .check(jsonPath("$.payment_transaction_id").saveAs("payment_transaction_id"))
     )
     .exec(
       http("Authorization flow")
      .post(authorization_endpoint)
      ***.body(ELFileBody("authorization.json"), Map("payment_token" -> "${payment_token}", "payment_transaction_id" -> "${payment_transaction_id}", "transaction_date" -> "${current_date}", "value" -> "${amount}"  ) ).asJSON***
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(jsonPath("$.transaction_details.transaction_status").is("Approved"))
      .check(jsonPath("$.transaction_details.transaction_status_code").is("0x20"))
      .check(jsonPath("$.transaction_details.payment_token").is("${payment_token}"))
      .check(jsonPath("$.transaction_details.payment_transaction_id").is("${payment_transaction_id}"))
      .check(jsonPath("$.transaction_details.transaction_date").is("${current_date}"))
     )

Thank You
Murali.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

- First, you're using Gatling 2.0.3 which is quite old, and will hit tons of bugs that have already been fixed, and miss tons of features. Current latest version is 2.1.7.
- Then, it looks like you're trying to do something similar to how things worked in Gatling 1, when we used Scalate for templating. This is not how things work now! With ELFileBody, you directly use Gatling EL in your template. Please read the documentation.